# Rascal MPL how to get all direct node descendants of a node itself

Tags: tree, rascal

I have a `list[Declaration] asts` and traverse it as follows:

```
visit(asts) {
    case node n: {
        println(getChildren(n));
    }
}
```

I realize that visit will by default traverse the nodes using a top-down strategy. At any point during this traversal, I would like to get the direct node descendants of this node in order to compare them.
Now, `getChildren(node T)` returns `list[value]`, see [getChildren](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/library/node/#Node-getChildren). How do I get all direct children as a `list[node]` instead? As a node is a part of a tree, I would expect a node to have node children of itself.

Additionally, how does one know that `lang::java::m3::AST` contains `node`s? There is no mention of this in either of [node](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Node/), [visit](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/rascal/expressions/visit/), [m3::AST](https://www.rascal-mpl.org/docs/library/lang/java/m3/ast/). I often find myself spending hours looking for use cases and feature examples like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type system works as follows

- `value` is the top
- `node` is a sub-type of `value` representing all tree-shaped abstractions
- All `data` types are all sub-types of `node` (like `data Expression = ...`)

So in `lang::java::m3::AST` everything defined with `data` declarations are also `node`'s. Some fields in their definitions are `str` or `int`. Those values are *not* of type `node`.

If you use `getChildren` as a generic function for any `data` type, then they could be anything, from integer to lists and sets and maps, etc. So its return type is `list[value]`.

If you want to filter the `nodes` from the list:

```
[n | node n <- getChildren(myNode)]
```

Or you could filter the nodes with location information:

```
[n | node n <- getChildren(myNode), n.src?]
```

Side note: most of the time, however, it is better to focus on specific Statement or Expression nodes rather then writing generic code. Source code analysis is typically specific to the source code. Generic algorithms are scarce and often inaccurate.

Comment: That's useful syntax! Regarding your side note: let's say one is doing something like AST-based clone detection. To approach this, one could start by dividing the code up into (sub)trees and find some way of comparing them. This approach could best be done generically right? As in, it could be rerun on different Java sources and still work.

Comment: Sure! That makes sense because you don't need to know anything about the nodes except their existence.

Comment: I noticed that several m3 nodes like `\java+compilationUnit(...)` (the root node of any *.java* file) and `\block(...)` (a statement sequence) return no children using `getChildren(myNode)`, even though I would expect them to be there.

Comment: Hi Teun; now that would be a serious bug, but it sounds rather unlikely. It would be very helpful if you have a small(ish) example of what you mean. Pls send it as a github issue on the rascal project? I sure hope it's not a bug :-)

Comment: Hi Jurgen, I attempted to recreate this but was not able to. Everything worked correctly. I think it's safe to call for a false alarm :)